# Wp Custom menu problem: the link is opened in the new tab and meanwhile the same tab

Tags: wordpress

I have problem with one wp custom menu, from Apperance > Menus i set that link to open in new tab.
When i go to the web site, and click on Forum (which is button who i want to open in new tab),  new tab with the forum is opened but, meanwhile in the main tab where it's supposed to be the WordPress i have the forum loaded and i must go back via button or shortcut.

My WordPress installation version is **3.1.1**

Thank you in advance.

Regards.
Ivelin Georgiev

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you have done already or not but this is how I always get menu items to open in new tabs and haven't ever had this problem.

Go to Appearance > Menus. At the top click Screen Options and check the bow that says 'Link Targets'. Then on the item you want to open in a new tab just select 'New Tab' for the link target when you expand that item's information.

If this doesn't work, or if this is already what you are doing I would try updating to the newest WordPress and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi, Corey. this when u describe is the method to set target="_blank" on specific link which i was do, but the problem is in main menu of the blog, public part, and there when i click that button which i made to open in new tab, he open the link location in the same and open new tab and load the same location and now i have 2 tabs, when i have that forum.

Comment: $h4cky I haven't ever seen that in wordpress so I can't help you sorry. My best guess would be to update to the newest WordPress and see if that fixes the problem

Comment: I will try it, but with that theme updating is my biggest problem, because the theme we use for that site is old... ty Cory.